# Implementing JFileChoser to current code

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I need help implementing JFileChooser to this program. For this problem I am suppose to make code that will read a file and display the number of characters, words, and lines in that file. My Professor commented on my assignment and said "still cannot find the file - use FileChooser and resubmit."  Any help is appreciated, thank you in advanced.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class C12E13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("The program will count the number of characters, words, and lines in a file");
            System.out.println("Input File Name");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String filename = input.nextLine();
            File source = new File(filename);
            if (!source.exists()) {
                System.out.println(filename + " File does not exist");
                System.exit(2);
            }

            try {
                Scanner infile = new Scanner(source);
                String line;
                int charactersCount = 0;
                int wordsCount = 0;
                int linesCount = 0;
                while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
                    line = infile.nextLine();
                    linesCount++;
                    String[] words = line.split("");
                    wordsCount += words.length;
                    for (String token : words) {
                        charactersCount += token.length();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Name of the input file:" + filename);
                System.out.println("Number of lines in the file:" + linesCount);
                System.out.println("Number of words in the file:" + wordsCount);
                System.out.println("Number of characters in the file:" + charactersCount);
                infile.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Do you want input again Y/N");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String inp = scan.nextLine();
                if (inp.equals("N")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to use a JFileChooser? Without showing us this attempt, how will we know what you're doing wrong and be able to help you?

Comment: Suggestion: solve by simplifying. Instead of trying to use a JFileChooser in a larger more complex program, try to create a separate small program where you use a JFileChooser to get and read a file, and do nothing more. Once you solve this, then it should be trivial to use the code in the larger program. If you fail in the attempt, you can then post this smaller code, code that doesn't have all the code not relevant to the problem at hand (as you're currently showing), but only relevant code.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using FileChooser. He told me to use it know. I am extremely confused on how to use Filechooser. I am just looking for some clarification on how it works/ somebody to explain how to use my current code in conjunction with Filechooser. Also this is my first time posting so I am not really sure want the usual rules/ format is

Comment: For clarification start with the tutorials. If still stuck, then come back with a much more specific question, one that shows your attempt.

Comment: Also, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Sorry for not reading those just trying to finish up a summer class and this is my last assignment. Would you be able to explain to me or show me on why my professor would get a cannot find a file error. Also thank you for linking the filechooser tutorial

Comment: He or anyone would get a the error if they put in the wrong relative or absolute file path. The file path is relative to the user's directory, something that can be found using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: Hey just want to say thank you for the help. I created a smaller program for JFileChooser and got that to work, just trying to fix my program now because the word counter is off